# visual studio code, tslint showing unchecked changes for staging

Tags: angular, git, visual-studio-code, tslint

I am using vs code for angular project with git source connected to my account. I added ts-lint with few rules. When I change one single line it is affecting for other changes. In staging process when I tried to remove them but its not working.
This below image is the original

[image]

Added "**the**" in line **67**.

[image]

When trying to ***stage*** the changes

[image]

**How to add only my changes here?**

Comment: From the difference image, it looks like you have removed blank spaces. You can notice those bank spaces on the red background. That's the reason you see addition of new lines on the right hand side

Comment: When I tried removing them from staged changes it is not working as expected

Comment: Do you have the formatOnSave option setted to true in your json config file?

Comment: no (u mean settings.json)

Comment: I tried by setting it false. but no luck

Answer (score 1):

The difference is you formatted the document or somehow removed the empty spaces in the document

Comment: I just added **"the"** as shown in the image with differences

Comment: If you zoom the difference image, you can clearly see two variations of Red in the LHS

Comment: Yeah but i did not add them. I just added **"the"** and saved the file. Automatically these spaces are added in stage changes

Comment: you might have pressed `alt + shift + F` or something else for formatting. So the empty spaces will be automatically removed by the VS Code formatter

Comment: No. when i change some lines of code that white spaces are added for staging